# Почему не работает анимация FloatingActionButton?

Tags: java, android, xml, анимация, android-animation

При нажатии на FAB должна запускаться анимация вращения кнопки на 45 градусов и обратно. Всё происходит во фрагменте. Есть разметка анимации в xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">
<rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="45"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="300"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

Подключаю её к FAB и вызываю методом `startAnimation()` в `onClick()`:

```
Animation rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fab_forward);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
        }
    });
```

И ничего не работает - кнопка немного дёргается и то, не всегда. Но если повесить на кнопку `onLongClick()`, то во время зажатия кнопки анимация воспроизводится до тех пор, пока нажатие не снимается (То есть анимация работает только пока метод обработчика исполняется). Делал анимацию в параллельном потоке - не помогло. Как сделать так, чтобы анимация длилась и после обработчика??

Comment: А если так: `fab.animate().rotate(45).setDuration(300);`? Не уверен, что "rotate" именно так пишется.

Comment: Да, сработало! День поиска решения и всего одна строчка, Спасибо!
Вот так работает: `fab.animate().rotation(45).setDuration(300);` @ЮрийСПб

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вот так анимировать:

```
fab.animate().rotate(45).setDuration(300);
```